# Why does this model unwrap despite having no seams marked on it?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I am very new to Blender and wanted to use the program to UV unwrap a 3D Pokemon model from the games to use it as a sewing pattern. Now after watching some basic tutorials about unwrapping and marking seams I've noticed that the model itself unwraps on certain edges with no existing seams or anything and I don't know why. I haven't found any help while Googling my problem yet and am hoping I can get some help here!

This is how it looks without adding seams and no UV unwrapping, just selecting the whole thing in UV editing mode:

[image: Model without adding seams and no UV unwrapping]

And this is after adding my own seams and UV unwrapping it:

[image: Added seams and UV unwrapped]

[This is where I got the model from](https://www.models-resource.com/3ds/pokemonxy/model/13879/)

Answer (score 2):

All primitive objects in Blender are unwrapped by default. So when you add your own seams and try to unwrap it, Blender discards the default UV and tries to unwrap UV according to your defined seams.

In your example, it looks like someone already unwrapped it and exported it as obj. So when you import it, you get the UVs but not the seams.

Comment: Oh that makes sense.
Is there a way to delete those UVs and replace them with my own or are they now a part of the model and there is no way to remove those?

Comment: Why would you want to delete the existing UVs? That represents someone's hard work that you now won't have to repeat. Unless there's something wrong with them, such as distorted texturing, consider leaving them alone. As Oye LKY pointed out, the seams mainly serve the purpose of assisting the unwrap process. Meaning that if the unwrap is done, the seams (for the most part) aren't needed any longer.

Comment: I understand that completely. My problem is that I want to use the unwrapped uv as a sewing pattern and therefore it needs to align with the colors of the model, which the original ones dont do

Comment: A model will always have a UV in blender, by default it would be based on the primitive (like plane, sphere, etc). You unwrap like you want, and new UV will replace any before it.

Comment: @Yuki Keep in mind, an object can have multiple different UV maps to choose from :). So you can keep the original one and also add your own.

Answer (score 1):

Once you are done marking seams manually, just go to UV mapping tab, go into Edit mode and press 'U' on your keyboard. In the resulting menu, select 'Unwrap'.

The seams in the first image are perfect if you ask me.

- you can change uvs any number of times as you want. But they won't align with the original texture that was painted.

Comment: the second image is what I got from unwrapping it in edit mode. I dont mind that it doesnt align with the original texture, but the original uv lines dont vanish after unwraping it again